# Variable inside variable not working in php with implode function

Tags: php, mysql

I am fetching some data from WordPress DB and also applying implode function in that. When I put the full table name inside that then it is working properly but when I store the table name in a variable and then putting that variable in code then it is not working.

Working code:

```
$result2 = $wpdb->get_results ('SELECT * FROM wp_xrd_references WHERE BINARY ref_code IN("'.implode('", "',$xrd2).'") ORDER BY FIELD(ref_code, "'.implode('", "',$xrd2).'");'); ?>
```

Not working after putting table name in variable

```
$xrd_references = $wpdb->prefix . "xrd_references";
$result2 = $wpdb->get_results ('SELECT * FROM '.$xrd_references.' WHERE BINARY ref_code IN("'.implode('", "',$xrd2).'") ORDER BY FIELD(ref_code, "'.implode('", "',$xrd2).'");'); ?>
```

There must be some syntax error because when I am putting this variable `$xrd_references` without implode function then the code is working properly. What is the syntax error I am doing here?

Comment: you do NOT use quotes within the SQL! so `$wpdb->get_results ('SELECT * FROM '.$xrd_references.' WHERE....` would be more appropriate

Comment: Sir, it is still not working like this `'.$xrd_references.'`

Answer (score 0):

When you are using $wpdb->prefix then you should concat table name without wp prefix (wp_)

WRONG: $xrd_references = $wpdb->prefix . "wp_xrd_references";

RIGHT: $xrd_references = $wpdb->prefix . "xrd_references";

Comment: Sorry sir, that I wrote by mistake but my question is that it is not taking variable inside it like `'.$xrd_references.'` or `"'.$xrd_references.'"`. Everywhere elase it is working fine but not with implode function. There must be some syntax error

Comment: I ran your query with my way query is fine I think problem in prefix and quote should be like: $xrd_references = $wpdb->prefix . "xrd_references"; $result2 = $wpdb->get_results ('SELECT * FROM '.$xrd_references.' WHERE BINARY ref_code IN("'.implode('", "',$xrd2).'") ORDER BY FIELD(ref_code, "'.implode('", "',$xrd2).'");');

Comment: I ran your query with wp_posts table and working fine.   global $wpdb;
$xrd2=array(10,14,25);
$xrd_references = $wpdb->prefix . "posts";
$result2 = $wpdb->get_results ('SELECT * FROM '.$xrd_references.' WHERE BINARY ID IN("'.implode('", "',$xrd2).'") ORDER BY FIELD(ID, "'.implode('", "',$xrd2).'");');